# Performances drops when using particles effects

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I have been working on a game for some time to create a fireworks show with libgdx and box2d.

The game is composed of an editor allowing the placement and adjustment of each fireworks display.
The other part concerns the spectacle part, the launching of fireworks in rows.

Each firework is composed of a body ejected with a certain speed to which is attached a particle effect allowing to simulate a trail (maximum 40 active particles).
At its peak, the trail disappears and the body of the bomb is destroyed.
At this moment another effect is started in order to simulate the explosion of the bomb (between 50 and 100 active particles).
In addition, several bodies (between 8 and 16) are ejected in different directions in order to simulate the stars to which a particle effect is attached in order to simulate their trail (between 10 and 50 particles).
At the end of their journey, each star has a particle effect (between 8 and 20) in order to simulate their explosion.

The problem comes from the fact that the number of fps drops greatly on Android when more than 10 fireworks are active simultaneously, here is the captures below to give an idea of ​​the rendering:

[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2pPsg.jpg)

[image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9z87q.jpg)

[image3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JEDHZ.jpg)

I obviously **use a pool to avoid recreating particle effects.** In addition, I make sure I already have some effects inside when starting the game.
This pool is an inner class located in my ParticleManager class which allows launching, updating, and rendering of effects.

**All my textures are contained in a single atlas (including particle).** All particles have the same sprite.

For the rendering of my particles I make sure that each effect **avoids flushing** the batch after its rendering with the following instruction, when a new effect is created:
`setEmittersCleanUpBlendFunction (false);`

Here is the render method of my ParticleManager class:

```
public void render (SpriteBatch sb) {
    if (effects.size == 0) return;

    // Manually change blendFunction.
    sb.setBlendFunction (GL20.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL20.GL_ONE);

    // Render all effects.
    for (int i = 0; i <effects.size; i ++)
        effects.get(i).draw(sb);

    // Manually reset blendFunction to his initial state.
    sb.setBlendFunction (GL20.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
}
```

I am using in my main Level class two cameras one for rendering my scene and one for rendering the HUD, so I call the function: `sb.setProjectionMatrix();` twice which results in flushing the batch twice, three times when effects are active which is due to the `sb.setBlendFunction();` method located in the render method of my ParticlesManager class.
So I come to 3 drawCalls.

Here is the code for my render method of my Level class without the superfluous functions:

```
public void render (float dt) {
    update(dt);

    Gdx.gl.glClearColor (0, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear (GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    // First draw call.
    sb.setProjectionMatrix (camera.combined);
    sb.begin ();
    backgroundManager.render (sb);
    worldManager.render (sb);

    // Second draw call if an effect is active.
    if (run)
        particlesManager.render (sb);

    // Second draw call if no effects, or third otherwise.
    sb.setProjectionMatrix (hud.getCamera (). combined);
    hud.render (sb);
    sb.end ();
}
```

So I do not see what optimizations I could finally make if it is possible to make some.
Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: FWIW, there's a great book about OpenGL in Android which sets up a similar scenario --> https://pragprog.com/titles/kbogla/opengl-es-2-for-android/ . I've implemented the particle system in that book and it's very responsive.

Answer (score 0):

I think try 2 things.

1. You have to return finished effects to the pool explicitly before they can be reused, so you get a slow down because the pool is exhausted and effectively generates -new- ones rather than reuse.
2. You need to remove from `effects` as well because otherwise you are iterating over finished effects.

```
    //This is the libGDX array for entry removal speed
    private final Array<PooledEffect> activeEffects = new Array<PooledEffect>(512);
```

and in render

```
       for (int i = activeEffects.size - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

            final PooledEffect effect = activeEffects.get(i);
            effect.update(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());
            effect.draw(spriteBatch);

            if (effect.isComplete()) {
                effect.reset();
                effect.free();
                activeEffects.removeIndex(i);

            }
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer however the problem does not come from the pool, indeed when an effect is finished I immediately put it back inside and I remove it from my active effects array like this : public void update (float dt) {
        for (int i = 0; i < effects.size; i++) {
                effects.get(i).update(dt);
                if(effects.get(i).isComplete()) {
                    pool.put(effects.get(i));
                    effects.removeValue(effects.get(i), false);
                    i--;
               }
        }
    }

Comment: Thanks for the reply anyway. The only other thing I could suggest is to change your texture packer settings i.e. premultiplyAlpha yes (i think this might be faster on android but can't find the reference anymore), force POT(power of 2), set min and mag filters to Nearest, and also try 0 for MSAA when setting the back buffer config. config.setBackBufferConfig(8, 8, 8, 8, 16, 0, GC.MSAA); and shrink the textureAtlas